# android widget only works after 2nd install

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

i implemented widgets , where the code starts like bellow

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {



    Log.d("MYDAYS", "--- widget update oncreate--");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateWidgets.class);

    extras = intent.getExtras();

}

@Override
//public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d("MYDAYS", "--- widget update onstartcommand--");
    String onlythatwidgetstr = "";

    if (extras != null) {
        // Log.d("MYDAYS", "--- in getExtras");
        onlythatwidgetstr = extras.getString("widgettableid");
        if (onlythatwidgetstr == null)
            onlythatwidget
```

the very strange thing, after first install, the widget says there is a loading problem. only after i reinstalled the app over my first installation, the widget appears as expected!  Any Ideas?